# preventing main view rendering after rendering a partial view

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i am using partial view to show some detail according to user selection in dropdown button and click a search button.and i am using javascript for laoding partial view.But afer loading partial view the main view getting load and after a moment my partial view is gone.please help.

My main view named CreateBidSecondStep

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="wrapper white-bg">
        <div class="row mar-xsm-b">
            <div class="col s12 l12 m12">
                <div class="step">
                    <span class="pull-left">Step 1 &gt;</span>
                    <span class="active pull-left">Step 2 &gt;</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="row mar-sm-b">
            <div class="col s12 m12 l12">
                <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
                    <div class="border-light">
                        <div class="heading24 mar-sm-l mar-sm-r">Bill of Material</div>
                        <div class="row">

                            <div class="col s8 m8 l8" id="billMaterial">
                                <div class="ProdHeading">Search</div>
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <label class="label pull-left">Item Code</label>
                                    @*<div class="editor-field">
                                        @Html.DropDownList("itemcode", Model.listofallitem, "Select Item")
                                    </div>*@
                                    <select class="browser-default pull-left width_120" name="itemcode" id="itemcodeid" >
                                        <option>Select Item Code</option> 
                                        @foreach(var item in Model.listofallitem)
                                         {
                                             <option value="@item.Value">@item.Value</option>
                                         }
                                         @*<option>Item Code</option>
                                        <option>Item Code</option>
                                        <option>Item Code</option>*@
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-left mar-lg-l">
                                    <label class="label pull-left">Item Name</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="pull-left" name="cap" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-left mar-lg-l">
                                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action" id="btnsearch">Search</button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                <div class="bdr-gray-b mar-sm-t mar-sm-b"></div>
                                <div class="pull-left">
                                    <label class="label pull-left width_120">Total Item Quantity</label>
                                    <input type="number" maxlength="5" class="pull-left width_80" name="cap" />
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <label class="label pull-left width_120">Item Quantity</label>
                                    <input type="number" class="pull-left width_80" name="cap" />
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <label class="label pull-left width_120">Location</label>
                                    <input type="text" class="pull-left width_80" name="cap" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-left mar-lg-l">
                                    <label>Description</label>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <textarea></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="pull-left mar-lg-l mar-md-t">
                                    <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" style="bottom:0px" type="submit" name="action">Add to BOM</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col s4 m4 l4">
                                <div class="table_h2" id="SAPdiv">

                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col s12 l12 m12 ">
                                <div class="table_h2">
                                    <table class="TableID2">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>Item Code</th>
                                                <th>Description</th>
                                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                                <th>Approved Supplied</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                            <td>&nbsp;</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row border-light mar-sm-t pad-sm">
                        <div class="col s12 l12 m12">
                            <div class="pull-left">
                            </div>
                            <div class="pull-right">
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">PREVIOUS</button>
                                <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">SEND TO ADVANCE PURCHASE</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

My partial view named _CreateBidSecondStep

```
model List<Company.Project.Shared.BiddingSecondStepSAP>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    if (Model != null)
    {
        <table class="TableID2">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Item Name</th>
                    <th>Item Code</th>
                    <th>SAP Quantity</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
           @foreach(var item in Model)
            {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @item.ItemId
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.ItemName
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.SAPQty
                </td>
            </tr>
            }
        </table>
    }
}
```

JavaScript Code to call partial view

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var url = '@Url.Action("SAPPartailView", "CreateBid")';
            $('#btnsearch').click(function () {
                var keyWord = $('#itemcodeid').val();
                $('#SAPdiv').load(url, { searchText: keyWord });
            })
</script>
```

Partial view action

```
public PartialViewResult SAPPartailView(string searchText)
        {
            BiddingSecondStepBDC _obj=new BiddingSecondStepBDC();
            List<BiddingSecondStepSAP> newlist = new List<BiddingSecondStepSAP>();
            newlist = _obj.GetItemSAP(searchText);
            return PartialView("_CreateBidSecondStepSAP",newlist);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `preventDefault()` method to stop the page from rendering.

```
        $('#btnsearch').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var keyWord = $('#itemcodeid').val();
            $('#SAPdiv').load(url, { searchText: keyWord });
        })
```